# Linear interpolation vectorized for faster calculation matrixwise

Tags: python, vectorization, interpolation

To calibrate large amounts of picture-Data in Python, I have to apply a correction elementwise to every pixel. Therefore, I've got a matrix with 200x200x2x9 values. The 200x200 representing the pixelposition, the 2x9 are 9 pairs of values, representing a base and a corresponding correction value for this particular pixel which need to be linear interpolated, polynominal interpolation does not work very well. For example this looks like this:

[image: Plot of an interpolation example]

Now I have a large amount of pictures and to save time I want to apply the correction of every pixel as fast as possible. I was thinking of a vectorized function. The input value from the picture should be a correction based on the position within the multiple points of the interpolation.

A for loop costs me a huge amount of time.

Can somebody help me with that?

***Edit

> I.e., for a single pixel, how do you wish to combine a scalar pixel value and the 2x9 interpolation matrix. What is the shape of your result, and how would the interpolation work?

Every pixel in the picture has a value between 0 and 16383. I want to find out, where in the series of linear interpolations this value is placed. In the example shown above 9 pairs of grey-value and the corresponding correction. So if the pixel has e.g. a value of ~6000, the calculated correction is -15. After the calculation, I'd like to have a 200x200 matrix with values (in this example) between ±15.

Comment: Your problem definition is incomplete/conflicting. You said that you have images (200x200) and correction values (2x9) for each pixel that you wish to interpolate between (which results in a 200x200x2x9 table for interpolation). What you didn't talk about is where you get the target at which you wish to interpolate. Is that a separate 200x200 array or a 200x200x9 array or something different entirely?

Comment: That is correct. Every picture taken has the size of 200x200 pixels.
Therefore, the correction-Data has 200x200 datasets as well, each containg 9 pairs for linear interpolation.

Comment: Okay. In that case, how do you expect to perform the interpolation? I.e., for a single pixel, how do you wish to combine a scalar pixel value and the `2x9` interpolation matrix. What is the shape of your result, and how would the interpolation work?

Comment: Every pixel in the picture has a value between 0 and 16383. I want to find out, where in the series of linear interpolations this value is placed. In the example shown above 9 pairs of grey-value and the corresponding correction. So if the pixel has e.g. a value of ~6000, the calculated correction is -15. After the calculation, I'd like to have a 200x200 matrix with values (in this example) between ±15.

Comment: I see. Could you update the question to include this information for others to see? I.e., that the 2x9 correction matrix are pairs of (px_value, correction), that you have anadditional 14-bit 200x200 image to which the correction is applied, and how to apply it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We start by defining some test code so that we have a minimum reproducible example. For simplicity I use the same base points for the interpolation per pixel. However, to test the robustness, I define the range so that we will have pixels below the lowest base point and ones above the highest.

```py
image = np.random.randint(0, 16383, (200, 200), dtype='i2')

correction = np.empty((200, 200, 2, 9), dtype='i2')
correction[..., 0, :] = np.linspace(
    0, 16383, num=11, endpoint=False, dtype='i2')[1:-1]
correction[..., 1, :] = np.random.randint(-16, 17, (200, 200, 9), dtype='i2')
```

To make indexing simpler, we flatten the image to 1D and separate the components from the correction matrix.

```py
origshape = image.shape
image = image.ravel()
correction = correction.reshape(image.shape + correction.shape[2:])
bases = correction[:, 0].T
basevalues = correction[:, 1].T
```

Now we want to find the value range per pixel.

```py
inrange = (image >= bases[:-1]) & (image <= bases[1:])
belowrange = image < bases[0]
aboverange = image > bases[-1]
```

Then we pick the corresponding values from the correction. We can use `np.choose` or `np.select` for this. This step could use some tuning so that the approach works with fancy-indexing. The results will be invalid for values that are above or below the base points. We correct this at a later step. Note that the lower and upper bases default to 0 and 1 for these cases. That avoids issues with the interpolation in these cases.

```py
lowerbases = np.select(inrange, bases[:-1])
upperbases = np.select(inrange, bases[1:], default=1)
lowervalues = np.select(inrange, basevalues[:-1])
uppervalues = np.select(inrange, basevalues[1:])
```

Now we apply a plain old linear interpolation.

```py
upperpercent = (image - lowerbases).astype('f4') / (upperbases - lowerbases)
lowerpercent = 1. - upperpercent
correctionvalues = (lowerpercent * lowervalues
                    + upperpercent * uppervalues).astype('i2')
```

For the values out of range, we can apply whatever condition we want. I choose to correct with the lowest or highest value. You may choose to extrapolate instead.

```py
correctionvalues[belowrange] = basevalues[0, belowrange]
correctionvalues[aboverange] = basevalues[-1, aboverange]
```

Now all that remains is applying the values and turning the image back into 2D

```py
image += correctionvalues
image = image.reshape(origshape)
```

Comment: I think your answer is pretty much equivalent to mine +- the choice of using `select` vs fancy indexing. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

For a single image, you can apply the correction in a vectorized fashion. First, here is some random example data:

```py
import numpy as np

rng = np.random.default_rng(42)

sample_image = rng.integers(0, 2**14, size=(200,200), dtype=np.uint16)

per_px_correction = np.empty((200,200, 9, 2), dtype=np.int32)
# anchors of known corrections
per_px_correction[..., 0] = rng.integers(0, 2**14, size=(200,200, 9), dtype=np.int32)
# correction values at anchors
per_px_correction[..., 1] = rng.integers(-15, 15, size=(200,200, 9), dtype=np.int32)

per_px_correction = np.sort(per_px_correction, axis=-2)
per_px_correction = np.swapaxes(per_px_correction, -2, -1)
```

with that out of the way, you can apply it to an image using the following steps:

```py
# introduce some useful names and update dtypes
img_normal = sample_image.astype(np.float64) / 2**14
anchors = per_px_correction[..., 0, :].astype(np.float64) / 2**14
values = per_px_correction[..., 1, :]

# work out the anchor points of the interpolation
anchor_is_greater = anchors > img_normal[..., None]
upper_anchor = np.argmax(anchor_is_greater, axis=-1)
upper_anchor = np.where(
    (upper_anchor == 0) & (anchor_is_greater[..., 0] == False),
    anchors.shape[-1] - 1,
    upper_anchor,
)
lower_anchor = np.maximum(upper_anchor - 1, 0)

# work out the corresponding values
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(200), np.arange(200))
upper_value = values[Y, X, upper_anchor]
lower_value = values[Y, X, lower_anchor]

# work out correction at pixel position
alpha = (img_normal - lower_anchor) / (upper_anchor - lower_anchor)
correction = (upper_value - lower_value) * alpha + lower_value
correction = np.round(correction).astype(np.int32)  # back to integer types

# apply correction
img_corrected = np.clip(sample_image + correction, 0, 2**14).astype(np.uint16)
```

A friend commented that this "looks like weird numpy magix", so here is a brief explanation of what is happening:

- In the first block we split the correction matrix and normalize image and anchor values to `[0, 1]`. This makes it easier to work, because we get descriptive names and have an easier time working out where between two anchors the pixel value is located.
- In the second block we work out the neighbouring anchors for each pixel, i.e., the closest anchor point that is bigger than the pixel value and the closest anchor point that is smaller than the pixel value. For this, I assume that the correction array is sorted by anchors (which we did during construction). This way, we only need to work out the lowest upper bound; the largest lower bound is then simply the previous anchor. While working out the upper anchor, we also need to handle the special case that no upper anchor exists (the pixel value is larger than the largest anchor). In this case, numpy will return np.argmax(...)=0. Thus, a 0 either means that the every anchor is greater than the pixel value or no anchor is greater. To disambiguate we use the `np.where`.
- We then use fancy indexing (advanced indexing) to get the correction values that correspond to each anchor.
- We then apply the interpolation to work out the correction at the given value. For this, we first work out where between the two anchors the pixel is located (`alpha`) where 0 means at the low anchor and 1 at the high anchor, and then we perform the interpolation.
- Finally, we take the computed correction coefficient and apply it to the image.

To apply this to multiple images, you can either apply this to one image at a time or in batches, i.e., you stack batches of images and batches of correction matrices along the 0-th axis and apply above snippet in bulk. Be careful though to not blow up your memory, because stacking a large amount of images can quickly eat up available RAM.